# Выполнить скрипт проверки перед всеми контроллерами

Tags: php, yii2

Есть несколько контроллеров. Необходимо, чтобы перед их обработкой срабатывал какой-то скрипт, в котором в случае прохождения условия, срабатывал redirect.

Пробовал реализовать след. образом

Во frontend/config/main.php в поле bootstrap добавил компонент `BeforeController`

```
'bootstrap' => ['log','BeforeController'],
```

Сам BeforeController:

```
class BeforeController extends \yii\base\Component
{    
    public function init()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
            return parent::init();

        $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        if(!$user->phone_confirmed_at)
            return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['sms/activate']);

        return parent::init();

    }

}
```

Проблема в том, что если обновить страницу `sms/activate` , то будет постоянный редирект. 
Но выполнить, что-то вроде:

```
if(Yii::$app->controller->id == 'sms')
        return true;
```

не могу, т.к. в контроллер мы еще не попали. 
Какие есть альтернативы данному решению?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы можете создать контроллер, в котором в методе beforeAction прописать ваш код. И все контроллеры наследовать от него. Там будет доступно Yii::$app->controller->id.
2. В вашем примере проверять с помощью `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl == 'sms/activate'`
3. В конфиге прописать:

   return [
       ...
       'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
           ...
       }
   ];

Comment: Не совсем подходит, т.к. есть контроллеры, которые наследуются от контроллеров из папки vendor.

Comment: Ну если у вас все контроллеры наследуются от `yii\web\Controller`, то создаете свой, наследуете от `yii\web\Controller` и он у вас будет базовый. А иначе можно создать трейт с методом `beforeAction` и подключить его во всех контроллерах

Comment: Не все наследуются от yii\web\Controller. 
По поводу трейтов думал, скорее остановлюсь на этом варианте

Answer (score 0):

Можно в каждом таком контроллере использовать магический метод __construct. Сначала будет проверка этого метода потом уже всё, что есть в контроллере.

Comment: дублировать код?

Comment: код положить в одно место, а в конструкторах просто его вызвать.